# MVC 3: render action in different controller from view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I must be missing something obvious.  I have a view A in controller B that needs to call and render an action method Y in controller Z.

Should I be doing something like this in view A ?  I'm getting errors in VS about how it can't resolve action '/Z/Y'

```
@Html.RenderAction("/Z/Y", new ModelUsedInActionMethodY())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use:

```
@Html.RenderAction("Y", "Z")
```

This will route to Action Method `Y` in `ZController`. See the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728607%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) for a complete list of method signatures for `Html.RenderAction()`.